# Making a collection of controls readonly

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, devexpress

I am currently working a web form application where I am using `Devexpress` controls. The controls I am using are (but not limited to):

1. BootstrapComboBox
2. BootstrapSpinEdit
3. BootstrapTextBox

The form is fairly big so what I am trying to achieve is pass in e.g. `IEnumerable<T>` and then loop over the collection and set the `ReadOnly` property to `true`. I know I can do one control at a time but I have over 50 controls so I was wondering if there is a more generic way.

I have the following snippet:

```
public static void MakeControlReadOnly<T>(this IEnumerable<T> controlCollection)
{
   foreach(var c in controlCollection)
      c.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

But I keep getting an error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'T' does not contain a definition for 'ReadOnly' and no extension method 'ReadOnly' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I understand the error but I am not sure how to overcome it.

Comment: Put a type constraint on T for the base type that contains the ReadOnly property

Comment: @bhmahler Can you provide an example please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try implicit type `T` as the `ASPxEditBase`, the base editable control of `DevExpress`

```
public static void MakeControlReadOnly<T>(this IEnumerable<T> controlCollection)
              where T: ASPxEditBase
{
   controlCollection.ToList().ForEach(x=> x.ReadOnly = true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this works perfectly. Though I had to change this line `controlCollection.ForEach(x=> x.ReadOnly = true);
` to a standard `foreach` loop because it kept throwing a error. So I suggest you update your answer for future readers too

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` shouldn't have a `ForEach` method (maybe you're thinking `List<T>`). Or is this a standard extension "kids these days" use? ^_^;

Comment: @Corak you were right. I updated the answer. thanks for the comment

Comment: @Code - you could have something like `public static class EnumerableExtensions { public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action) { foreach(var item in items) { action(item); } } }` if you'd want that fancy one-liner, but other than that, it doesn't do much.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a type constraint on the generic for the base class that contains the readonly property

```
public static void MakeControlReadOnly<T>(this IEnumerable<T> controlCollection) where T: BaseType //Set this to the correct base type
{
   foreach(var c in controlCollection)
      c.ReadOnly = true;
}
```